# Push an array to a multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to take an array, `inArray`, that changes with each iteration of a `for()` loop and push it to a multidimensional array, `medArray`. There are two different methods below that are slightly different and one achieves the goal whereas the second outputs `medArray` such that is has three arrays within it and they are all equal to the last iteration of `inArray`.

I'm confused as to why this works:

```
var inArray = [1, 2, 3];

var medArray = [];



for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    inArray[i] += 1;
//The difference is this line below
    var test = [inArray[0], inArray[1], inArray[2]];
    medArray.push(test)
    console.log(medArray);
 }
```

But this doesn't work:

```
var inArray = [1, 2, 3];

var medArray = [];

 for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    inArray[i] += 1;
//The difference is this line below
    var test = inArray;
    medArray.push(test)
    console.log(medArray);
 }
```

When I individually assign the values of `test` to be the individual value of `inArray` it works but when I assign the two arrays to be equal, it doesn't work. What is happening?

Answer (score 1):

> *the second outputs `medArray` such that is has three arrays within it and they are all equal to the last iteration of `inArray`.*

Actually, the second code block pushes *the same* array to `medArray` three times. When you say `temp = inArray` that doesn't create a copy of the array, it creates another reference to the same array. (So if, after the loop, you were to say `medArray[0][0] = 10` you'd find that `medArray[1][0]` and `medArray[2][0]` now both equal `10` too, because `medArray[0]`, `medArray[1]` and `medArray[2]` all reference the same array.)

If you want to make a copy of the `inArray` array then use [the array `.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var temp = inArray.slice();
```

Then `temp` would be a new array that has the same elements as `inArray`. Which is what you did in your first code block with `test = [inArray[0], inArray[1], inArray[2]];`.

Or you can omit the `temp` variable and just say:

```
medArray.push(inArray.slice());
```

(`.slice()` can also be used to copy just a portion of an array if you call it with arguments, but called with no arguments it copies the whole array.)

In context:

```js
var inArray = [1, 2, 3];
var medArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    inArray[i] += 1;
    medArray.push(inArray.slice());
}
console.log(medArray);
```

Comment: You are the greatest! I have struggled with that for hours.